# No routes matched location "/login" react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to organize the routes in `react-router-dom v6. And here is my flow:

**root AppComponent**

```
function AppComponent() {
  return <AppRoute />;
}
```

**AppRoute.js (base routes)**

```
const AppRoute = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <GuestRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**GuestRoute**

```
const GuestRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <GuestLayout>
      <Routes>
        <Route {...rest} element={<Component />} />
      </Routes>
    </GuestLayout>
  );
};
```

**GuestLayout**

```
const GuestLayout = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
  );
};
```

But, when I go to `/login`, it is not breaking the page, but it is still showing a warning of `No routes matched location "/login"`. I am using `react-router-dom v6`

Comment: Although your code is a bit convoluted, it appears to work. Check this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6-8phs5?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I checked the sandbox and there also on the console, it showing warnings like `No routes matched location "/"`

Comment: You aren't rendering a route for the "/" path.

Comment: I don't get it, could you please elaborate, why it is showing warning on my case?

Comment: You've not any `Route path="/" element={ .... } />` in your `Routes` component, and so this is the cause of the warning. See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6-8phs5?file=/src/App.js). Can you clarify what sort of route organization you are going for? I ask because in version 6 of `react-router-dom` they've largely moved away from custom route components. I could make a refactoring suggestion but I'd prefer to understand your usecase first.

Comment: Then what would be the best way to handle multiple layouts with react-router-dom v6, could you please share some articles or tutorials which I could follow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are trying to share multiple layouts then `react-router-dom@6` handles this nicely out-of-the-box.

[Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)

Example refactoring to use `GuestLayout` container:

```html
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<GuestLayout />}>   // <-- layout wraps children routes
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} /> // <-- "/login"

    // Optional index route if no nested routes match
    <Route
      index                                    // <-- "/"
      element={<div>Default Page Content</div>}
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This works by having the parent layout container component rendering an `Outlet` for its nested routes to be rendered.

```
const GuestLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div /* your crazy layout styling */ >
      <h1>This is the Guest Layout Page</h1>
      <Outlet /> // <-- matched nested route rendered here
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6 (forked)]

Answer (score 6):

Not directly a solution but a small typo caused by headaches.
Basically, check your route separator character "/". I had accidentally put "" which is obviously incorrect.

Another good way to debug issues is not use all paths "*" as the last route in Routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<p>Path not resolved</p>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this once with a bad permission handling using a useContext hook for authentication.

You can add a fall back route and check this:

```
<Route path="*" element={<div> Not Found or You do not have permission.</div>}/>
```

Also this happens sometimes when the element/component given in the route uses Axios/Fetch calls that fails with permission denials.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `BrowserRouter` was not rendered at the topmost root level component. Moving it at the root level as the react-router-dom [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#browserrouter) mentions fixed the error.