# React router v6 nested routes not displaying child element

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/parent" element={<h1>I am parent</h1>}>
      <Route path="child" element={<h1>I am child</h1>} />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={
        <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
          <p>There's nothing here!</p>
        </main>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I visit the route http://localhost:3000/parent/child I am expecting the following output.

> I am parent I am child

But instead I am getting the output

> I am parent

```
"dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.19.4",
    "react-router-dom": "6",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "zustand": "^3.6.5"
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900623/no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6/69917419#69917419

Answer (score 11, accepted):

React v6 needs to know where exactly you want your child element to be displayed, within the parent element. For this, you need to add a `<Outlet />` component.

See https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/basic

So your example should be written:

```js
return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/parent" element={<><h1>I am parent</h1><Outlet /></>}>
      <Route path="child" element={<h1>I am child</h1>} />
    </Route>
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={
        <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
          <p>There's nothing here!</p>
        </main>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```