# React router warnings no matched routes already use outlet for layout purposes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm having a problem with this error `No routes matched location`, all my navigation does that. Already tried implementing with this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900623/no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6), but still got the same error or Am I missing something here?

Here is my code:

App.tsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<SignInForm />} />
          <Route path="/signin" element={<SignInForm />} />
          <Route path="/newpassword" element={<NewPassword />} />
{/*some other routes here*/}
         </Route>
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here is my code for LoginLayout.tsx:

```
    function LoginLayout() {
  return (
    <div className="content">
      <Container className="signin-wrapper">
        <Row>
          <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <ImageSection />
          </Col>
          <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <Outlet />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginLayout;
```

I just post small part of my code, and my react-router-dom version is `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",`

Sample from console:

[image]

Comment: The code appears to run without issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-warnings-no-matched-routes-already-use-outlet-for-layout-purposes-21fwej). Does it repro on your end if you kill all code watchers/hot-reloaders and restart the development server (*`npm start`*)?

Comment: Hi Sir @DrewReese, what do you mean by watchers/hot-reloaders? sorry I'm still new with react. I'm using yarn start, does it matter if I use npm start?

Comment: When running in development mode there's typically a watcher waiting for code updates, i.e. like when you edit and save a file, that then rebuilds your app live. Most of the time this works without issue, sometimes it fails and you need to effectively restart the entire process.