# No match for the location, using useParams, even though defined with react-router-dom's Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React App and the problem comes when I try to use `useParams` with a location.
For the following Route worked perfectly, being able to access the category in the `CategoryVerses` component:

```
<Route path="/versete/:category" element={<CategoryVerses />} />
```

But for the next Route, returns me a warning saying that there are "No matches for the location ..."

```
<Route path="/verset/:abrev.:chapter.:verse" element={<Verse />} />
```

I also tried this way, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69900623/no-routes-matched-location-login-react-router-dom-v6):

```
<Route path="/verset" element={<Verse />}>
  <Route path="?:abrev.:chapter.:verse" element={<Verse />} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters needs to be slash separated, not by dots. Try like this:

```
<Route path="/verset/:abrev/:chapter/:verse" element={<Verse />} />
```

**Edit**:
If you need to create and access a route by dots, you can combine all the params into one variable:

```
<Route path="/verset/:allCombined" element={<Verse />} />
```

and then access them like this:

```
const { allCombined } = useParams();

const abrev = allCombined.split('.')[0];
const chapter = allCombined.split('.')[1];
const verse = allCombined.split('.')[2];

//OR directly destruct from array returned by split
const [abrev, chapter, verse] = allCombined.split('.');
```

Comment: Can I not bring everything under one "route"?  Lke in this link: https://www.bible.com/bible/59/MAT.5.ESV. Is this the only way? You see in that link those are dot-separated.

Comment: I have edited my answer, so now your `allCombined` param will be a string which will look like `1.2.3`. Hope this helps.

Comment: `const [abrev, chapter, verse] = allCombined.split('.');` is more succinct and ***DRY***.